# Running PIG scripts on Cassandra Table

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig, cassandra-cli

I am using 
Cassandra-1.2 with patch 5234 - Table created through CQL3 are not accessible to Pig
Hadoop - 1.1.2
pig 0.11.1

I have a table in Cassandra

datatypetest (num int PRIMARY KEY, ascii ascii, blob blob, text text, varnum varint);

and the test data in datatypetest is

```
 num | ascii | blob   | text | varnum
-----+-------+--------+--------+------
  13 |   126 | 0x0003 | John | null
```

I ran the following PIG Script

```
test1 = LOAD 'cassandra://keyspace1/datatypetest' USING CassandraStorage() AS 
(num:int, columns: bag {T: tuple(name, value)});
```

And the output is as follows in the alias test1

```
(12,{((),),((ascii),125),((blob),��),((text),deepak)})
```

As you can see in the output, it is not in the following format

```
(<row_key>,{(<column_name1>,<value1>),(<column_name2>,<value2>)})
```

The inner bag has tuple which has another inner tuple and the first inner tuple which I presume is the key is empty.

I cannot use columns.ascii or columns.blob or columns.text to access the columns tuples like below and get an exception

```
test2 = FOREACH test1 GENERATE num, columns.text;
2013-07-29 09:11:58,488 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - 
ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 3, column 8> pig script failed to validate:    
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1128: 
Cannot find field text in name:tuple(),value:bytearray
```

How can I access the column tuples.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `CassandraStorage` when referencing tables created using CQL3. `CassandraStorage` is analogous to the Thrift API. When accessing CQL3 tables, use `CqlStorage`:

```
test1 = LOAD 'cql://keyspace1/datatypetest' USING CqlStorage();
```

This should give you name/value tuples for the columns and their contents. The response should look something like this:

```
((name,13),(ascii,126),(blob,"blobvalue"),(text,John))
```

However, there does seem to be a mismatch between the returned collection and the schema that `CqlStorage` generates. ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391552/cqlstorage-generates-wrong-pig-schema).)