# CCE: BinSedesTuple cannot be cast to String

Tags: apache-pig, cql3

I am trying to process the following data:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN( vitalStatus);
DUMB B;
(value,LIVING)
(value,LIVING)
(value,LIVING)
(value,DECEASED)
(value,LIVING)
(value,DECEASED)
(value,DECEASED)
(value,LIVING)
```

But when I try to filter it (FILTER A BY vitalStatus MATCHES 'DECEASED')
What am I doing wrong?

I get the following error:

```
2013-08-23 08:47:16,290 [Thread-4] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.BinSedesTuple cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.PORegexp.getNext(PORegexp.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POFilter.getNext(POFilter.java:148)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNext(POForEach.java:233)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:460)
...
```

Comment: What is the output of `DESCRIBE B;`?

Comment: B: {vitalStatus: chararray}

Comment: If it matters the data is coming from CqlStorage, the cassandra client for pig.

Comment: What about `DESCRIBE A;`?

Comment: This seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391552/cqlstorage-generates-wrong-pig-schema

Comment: A: {cancer: chararray,barcode: chararray,row_id: bytearray,key: chararray,vitalStatus: chararray}

Comment: I have submitted a issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5941

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by applying fix from [CASSANDRA-5941](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5941)

As Alex Lui, mentioned in my ticket:

```
git clone http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra.git
cd cassandra
git checkout cassandra-1.2
patch -p1 < 5867-bug-fix-filter-push-down-1.2-branch.txt
ant
```